# UNKNWON TRANSACTION TO MY WALLET

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, hack, convert

[image: I received that amount from an unknown source. what also troubles me is that my wallet displaces a much larger amount than i received which i cant explain.my gool is to convert that amount to EUR but im afraid of a potential smart contract that involves a 99% fee which will be activated once i move the founds i read that this is a possibility on reddit plus the possibility of a hack. is there a way to securly transfer the worth of these founds to my bank account without losing it]

I received that amount from an unknown source. what also troubles me is that my wallet displaces a much larger amount than i received which i cant explain.my gool is to convert that amount to EUR but im afraid of a potential smart contract that involves a 99% fee which will be activated once i move the founds i read that this is a possibility on reddit plus the possibility of a hack. is there a way to securly transfer the worth of these founds to my bank account without losing it.